# UILabel slides down to send error message

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add a UILabel to the view which slides down when an error occurs to send error message to user. The prototype of it is like the one Facebook or Instagram shows. Here is the codes I have worked out so far:

```
func sendErrorMessage(errorString: String) {
    self.errorLabel.text = errorString
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
            self.errorLabel.frame.height = 30 //Cannot assign to the result of this expression
            self.topView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: {
            (finished: Bool) in var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: Selector(), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    })
}
```

`errorLabel` is now already in storyboard but with the height of 0 and `topView` is the superview of `errorLabel`. I am quite new to these methods so I am stuck here. I don't understand why that error occurred and what the `selector` should do here. There is also a step that I haven't done here that the `errorLabel` should slide up to disappear after three seconds and that's why I need a `timer` here.

Plus: Is there any difference if I create a new `errorLabel` whenever it is needed instead of make it ready before in storyboard? I mean in app performance of memory management.

UPDATE

I need `errorLabel` in many `ViewController`s, so following the idea of @Sajjon, I tried to subclass `UILabel`. Here is my subclass `ErrorLabel`:

```
class ErrorLabel: UILabel {
    var errorString: String?

    func sendErrorMessage() {
        self.text = errorString

        showErrorLabel()
        let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: "hideErrorLabel", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    func animateFrameChange() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { self.layoutIfNeeded() }, completion: nil)
    }
    func showErrorLabel() {
        let oldFrame = self.frame
        let newFrame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, oldFrame.origin.y, oldFrame.height + 30, oldFrame.width)
        self.frame = newFrame
        self.animateFrameChange()
    }
    func hideErrorLabel() {
        let oldFrame = self.frame
        let newFrame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, oldFrame.origin.y, oldFrame.height - 30, oldFrame.width)
        self.frame = newFrame
        self.animateFrameChange()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using auto layout, you should position the label using constraints and CTRL drag them into you code. Then in the code set the constraint values before the animation block. Otherwise you will find, on iOS8 at least, that the label may snap to its original position after the animation and layout is called forcing any constraints to reset the frame back to its original position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ought to use autolayout for this, when showing the errorLabel (or some container view that it is inside), I would give the height constraint your wished value (30). And hiding it again by giving the constraint a value of 0.

I would create an UIView extension and put code for animating this height change.

This is **untested code**, but will give you an idea of how to achieve it.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var errorLabelHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private let errorLabelHeightVisible: CGFloat = 30
    private let hideDelay: NSTimeInterval = 3
    private var timer: NSTimer!

    func sendErrorMessage(errorString: String) {
        errorLabel.text = errorString
        showOrHideErrorView(false)
    }

    func showOrHideErrorView(hide: Bool = true, animated: Bool = true) {
        if hide {
            errorLabelHeightConstraint.constant = 0
        } else {
            errorLabelHeightConstraint.constant = errorLabelHeightVisible
        }

        let automaticallyHideErrorViewClosure: () -> Void = {
            /* Only scheduling hiding of error message, if we just showed it. */
            if !hide {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    () -> Void in
                    automaticallyHideErrorMessage()
                })
            }
        }

        if animated {
            view.animateConstraintChange(completion: {
                (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                automaticallyHideErrorViewClosure()
            })
        } else {
            view.layoutIfNeeded()
            automaticallyHideErrorViewClosure()
        }
    }

    /* Selector method */
    func hideError() {
        showOrHideErrorView()
    }

    func automaticallyHideErrorMessage() {
        if timer != nil {
            if timer.valid {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
            timer = nil
        }
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(hideDelay, target: self, selector: "hideError", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)    
    }
}


extension UIView {

    static var standardDuration: NSTimeInterval { get { return 0.3 } }

    func animateConstraintChange(duration: NSTimeInterval = standardDuration, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
        UIView.animate(durationUsed: duration, animations: {
            () -> Void in
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80294/discussion-on-answer-by-sajjon-uilabel-slides-down-to-send-error-message).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, CGRect objects used by views for their frame or bounds properties are immutable. Instead of trying to directly modify the view's frame, create a new CGRect which contains the desired final size and position and assign that to the view's frame in the animation block.

```
//Don't do this.
myView.frame.size.height = 30; 

// Do this instead.
CGRect oldRect = myView.frame;
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(oldRect.origin.x, oldRect.origin.y, oldRect.size.width, 30);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    myView.frame = newFrame;
};
```

Also, I would strongly suggest making the label show and hide my changing its y position on and off the top of the screen, rather than changing the height to 0, which can have some unintended layout consequences

Answer (score 0):

For Change height Try This:

`self.errorLabel.frame.size.height = 30`

Answer (score 0):

you need to set Frame of UILable instead of its height only.

```
func sendErrorMessage(errorString: String) {
self.errorLabel.text = errorString
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
        self.errorLabel.setFrame = CGRectmake(self.errorLabel.frame.origin.x,self.errorLabel.frame.origin.y,self.errorLabel.frame.size.width,30) 
        self.topView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: {
        (finished: Bool) in var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: Selector(), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
   })
}
```